# Isolating String Output

Tags: string, go

I currently have a script that performs an os command, that returns a great deal of data, at the end of the data it gives a total such that:

N Total.

N can be any number from 0 upward.

I want to perform this command, and take N then put it into a value.  I have the command running and I'm storing it in a bytes.Buffer, however I'm unsure how to scrape this so that I only get the number.  The "N Total." string is always at the end of the output.  Any help would be appreciated as I've seen various different methods but they all seem quite convoluted.

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying to accomplish this with so far?

Comment: Maybe another os call for `tail -n1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by `\n` and get the last line.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    output := `
Some os output
Some more os output
Again some os output
1001 Total`

    // If you're getting the string from the bytes.Buffer do this:
    // output := myBytesBuffer.String()

    outputSplit := strings.Split(output, "\n") // Break into lines

    // Get last line from the end.
    // -1 assumes the numbers in the last line. Change it if its not.
    lastLine := outputSplit[len(outputSplit)-1]

    lastLine = strings.Replace(lastLine, " Total", "", -1) // Remove text

    number, _ := strconv.Atoi(lastLine) // Convert from text to number

    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

peterSO points out that for big output the above may be slow.

Here's another way that uses a compiled regexp expression to match against a small subset of bytes.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // Create regular expression. You only create this once.
    // Would be regexpNumber := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+) Total`) for you
    regexpNumber := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+) bits physical`)

    // Whatever your os command is
    command := exec.Command("cat", "/proc/cpuinfo")
    output, _ := command.Output()

    // Your bytes.Buffer
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write(output)

    // Get end of bytes slice
    var end []byte
    if b.Len()-200 > 0 {
        end = b.Bytes()[b.Len()-200:]
    } else {
        end = b.Bytes()
    }

    // Get matches. matches[1] contains your number
    matches := regexpNumber.FindSubmatch(end)

    // Convert bytes to int
    number, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(matches[1])) // Convert from text to number
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

Comment: The question says: "a great deal of data, at the end of the data it gives a total." Splitting a great deal of data into lines is unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: I gave this a go and it seems as though "matches" is nothing, I presume I probably have to modify the regex string, as my test server spits out "0 Total" at all times.

Edit:Just noticed the end output has 1 leading new line and 2 new lines after it, not sure if this would be causing a lack of a match.

Comment: If there's more content after "n Total" you may want to change 20 to a higher number.

Comment: Try fmt.Println(string(b.Bytes()[b.Len()-100:])) and see what the output is. Does it include your total value?

Comment: if I tailor it down to -11 it does (anything over 11 with my test case is out of bounds due to the very very low amount of output my test server gives).  Which is why I don't understand why the regex doesn't match, even tested it on a regex tester and its found.

Comment: I've modified the code so that you won't get an out of bounds error due to very low output. I've also replaced the test string with an actual os command and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bufio.Scanner to read the command's output line-wise. Then just remember the last line and parse it once the command has finished.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    cmd := exec.Command("fortune")
    cmd.Stdout = w
    go func() {
            cmd.Run()
            r.Close()
            w.Close()
    }()

    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    var lastLine string
    for sc.Scan() {
            line := sc.Text()
            fmt.Println("debug:", line)

            if strings.TrimSpace(line) != "" {
                    lastLine = line
            }
    }

    fmt.Println(lastLine)
}
```

Sample output:

```
debug: "Get back to your stations!"
debug: "We're beaming down to the planet, sir."
debug: -- Kirk and Mr. Leslie, "This Side of Paradise",
debug: stardate 3417.3
stardate 3417.3
```

Parsing lastLine is left as an excercise for the reader.